# Optaplanner optaweb-vehicle-routing problem multiple deposits and starting depot different form arrival depot

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

Hi I'm currently using the kiegroup/optaweb-vehicle-routing project I wanted to know if there is a way to set more deposits and to have the starting deposit that is different from the arriving deposit? So I don't want to have more deposits and the deposit is used as starting and ending point for the solution.

So, for example, I have just 1 vehicle and I want to start from depot-1 go to a location and then end the route going to depot-2.

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is currently missing but it definitely sounds like something we want to add in the future.

Pull requests are welcome but please file an issue on GitHub or at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER first so that we can discuss the requirements and break the task down into smaller sub-tasks.